# Reordering matrix columns based on specific prefix in few column names in R

Tags: r, matrix, alphabetical

I have a `matrix` in R with column names.

```
> colnames(m)
 [1] "caz_RNAi1_R1"     "caz_RNAi2_R1"     "cg1316_RNAi1_R1"  "cg1316_RNAi2_R1"  "cg4612_RNAi1_R1" 
 [6] "cg4612_RNAi2_R1"  "Dp1_RNAi1_R1"     "Dp1_RNAi2_R1"     "fmr1_RNAi1_R1"    "fmr1_RNAi2_R1"   
[11] "GFP_RNAi1_R1"     "GFP_RNAi2_R1"     "GFP_RNAi3_R1"     "GFP_RNAi4_R1"     "GFP_RNAi5_R1"    
[16] "GFP_RNAi6_R1"     "hrb87f_RNAi1_R1"  "hrb87f_RNAi2_R1"  "hrb98de_RNAi1_R1" "hrb98de_RNAi2_R1"
```

Now, some of the column names has prefix `GFP`. I want to reorder the matrix columns so that the columns having this prefix in their names would be the beginning columns and rest of the columns would be alphabetically ordered among themselves.

So `colnames(m)` should be ordered something like:

```
"GFP_a", "GFP_b", "GFP_c",..."GFP_z", "a", "b","c","d", ....
```

What's the way to do this?

Comment: You want a mixed order here that will order both characters and numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
 m[order(-(grepl('^GFP', m))+1L)]
```

where `m` is from @Mamoun Benghezal's post.  In the example, it is already ordered alphabetically, but in case it is not

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <-sample(m)
 m1[order(m1)][order(-(grepl('^GFP',m1[order(m1)]))+1L)]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
m <-  c("caz_RNAi1_R1", "caz_RNAi2_R1", "cg1316_RNAi1_R1", "cg1316_RNAi2_R1", "cg4612_RNAi1_R1",
        "cg4612_RNAi2_R1", "Dp1_RNAi1_R1", "Dp1_RNAi2_R1", "fmr1_RNAi1_R1", "fmr1_RNAi2_R1",
        "GFP_RNAi1_R1", "GFP_RNAi2_R1", "GFP_RNAi3_R1", "GFP_RNAi4_R1", "GFP_RNAi5_R1",
        "GFP_RNAi6_R1", "hrb87f_RNAi1_R1",  "hrb87f_RNAi2_R1",  "hrb98de_RNAi1_R1", "hrb98de_RNAi2_R1")
sort(m[grep(pattern="^GFP", x = m )]) # beginning with GFP
## [1] "GFP_RNAi1_R1" "GFP_RNAi2_R1" "GFP_RNAi3_R1" "GFP_RNAi4_R1" "GFP_RNAi5_R1" "GFP_RNAi6_R1"
sort(m[-grep(pattern="^GFP", x = m )]) # do not begin by GFP
##     [1] "caz_RNAi1_R1"     "caz_RNAi2_R1"     "cg1316_RNAi1_R1"  "cg1316_RNAi2_R1"  "cg4612_RNAi1_R1"  "cg4612_RNAi2_R1"  "Dp1_RNAi1_R1"     "Dp1_RNAi2_R1"     "fmr1_RNAi1_R1"    "fmr1_RNAi2_R1"   
##    [11] "hrb87f_RNAi1_R1"  "hrb87f_RNAi2_R1"  "hrb98de_RNAi1_R1" "hrb98de_RNAi2_R1"
c(sort(m[grep(pattern="^GFP", x = m )]),  sort(m[-grep(pattern="^GFP", x = m )])) # ordered columns
```

Comment: There is no ordering element here.

Comment: Even if it is unnecessary in this example, `sort` will do the ordering of columns.